# PHP function rename permission denied although permission set on 0777 for source and target folder

Tags: php, html, centos, rename

I want to move a file from one directory to another director with the rename() function.
But I get the Error:

> Warning:
> rename(/var/www/html/infodisplay-dashboard/uploads/Abo_Bonus.png,/var/www/html/infodisplay-dashboard/New/Abo_Bonus.png):
> Permission denied in /var/www/html/infodisplay-dashboard/index.php on
> line 43

I have the permissions on the source and target folder and also on the file set to 0777. Owner of the directories and files is the apache user.

I am working on Rocky Linux release 8.5 (Green Obsidian)

PHP Version is 8.1.0

The code looks like this:

```
$pfadOld = "/var/www/html/infodisplay-dashboard/uploads/".$fileName;
$pfadNew = "/var/www/html/infodisplay-dashboard/New/".$fileName;
rename($pfadOld, $pfadNew);
```

I know there are thousands of similar questions, but none of them helped me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem:
I needed to disable SELinux.
Open /etc/selinux/config in an editor and disable SELinux: SELINUX=disabled
After that reboot the system and everything should work as it should.